# asp.net boilerplate incorrectly saving entity as deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

This is my first post on here so sorry if I don't provide enough information.

We are using ABP v5.1 with a SQL Server database. We have a `Message` entity which inherits from `FullAuditedEntity<int>` with various IDs for message state, type, and associated company.

To get the values associated with the state and type id's we get a lookup from a table in the database which has Id, Group, and Title columns.

The class for CRUD operations for messages is `MessageAppService` which inherits from `AsyncCrudAppService` and has overrides for create and update which also calls the overridden base methods after doing some input manipulation using the lookup values.

The issue is that when I submit an update to a message which calls `MessageAppService.UpdateAsync`, it sets the `IsDeleted` boolean to true when it is false in the input. This only happens if I try to get a lookup from the database. Commenting out the code to get the lookups results in the expected behaviour.

I copied the code for `AsyncCrudAppService.UpdateAsync` into my code to see where it changes `IsDeleted` to `false` and it is changing it on the `await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()` call.

How can I stop it from marking the message as deleted when it clearly shouldn't be?

Here is the relevant code:

MessageAppService

```cs
public class MessageAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Message, MessageDto, int, PagedMessageResultRequestDto,
        CreateUpdateMessageDto, CreateUpdateMessageDto>, IMessageAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Message> _messageRepository;
        private readonly MessageGroupAppService _messageGroupAppService;
        private readonly RecipientGroupAppService _recipientGroupAppService;
        private readonly MessageRecipientAppService _messageRecipientAppService;
        private readonly RecipientAppService _recipientAppService;
        private readonly RoleManager _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;
        private readonly INotificationPublisher _notificationPublisher;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly LookUpAppService _lookUpAppService;

        public MessageAppService(IRepository<Message> messageRepository,
                                MessageGroupAppService messageGroupAppService,
                                RecipientGroupAppService recipientGroupAppService,
                                MessageRecipientAppService messageRecipientAppService,
                                RecipientAppService recipientAppService,
                                RoleManager roleManager,
                                UserManager userManager,
                                INotificationPublisher notificationPublisher,
                                IConfiguration configuration,
                                LookUpAppService lookUpAppService)
            : base(messageRepository)
        {
            _messageRepository = messageRepository;
            _messageGroupAppService = messageGroupAppService;
            _recipientGroupAppService = recipientGroupAppService;
            _messageRecipientAppService = messageRecipientAppService;
            _recipientAppService = recipientAppService;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _notificationPublisher = notificationPublisher;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _lookUpAppService = lookUpAppService;
        }

        public override async Task<MessageDto> CreateAsync(CreateUpdateMessageDto input)
        {
            return await ProcessMessage(input, true);
        }

        public override async Task<MessageDto> UpdateAsync(CreateUpdateMessageDto input)
        {
            return await ProcessMessage(input, false);
        }

        private async Task<MessageDto> ProcessMessage(CreateUpdateMessageDto input, bool create)
        {
            // Calling this causes `base.UpdateAsync` to set `IsDeleted` to `true`
            var messageState = (await _lookUpAppService.GetLookup("MessageState", input.StateLookUpId)).Title;

            var emailApprovers = false;
            var sendMessage = false;

            switch (messageState)
            {
                case "Pending":
                    // Calling this causes `base.UpdateAsync` to set `IsDeleted` to `true`
                    var company = (await _lookUpAppService.GetLookup("Company", input.CompanyLookUpId)).Title;

                    var permissionName = $"{company.ToUpper()}.Message.Approve";

                    if (!await PermissionChecker.IsGrantedAsync(permissionName))
                    {
                        emailApprovers = true;
                    }

                    break;
                case "Approved":
                    input.ApprovingUserId = AbpSession.UserId.Value;
                    sendMessage = true;
                    break;
            }

            MessageDto message;
            if (create)
            {
                message = await base.CreateAsync(input);
            }
            else
            {
                // `AsyncCrudAppService.UpdateAsync(input)` code from ABP git repo
                CheckUpdatePermission();

                var entity = await GetEntityByIdAsync(input.Id);

                MapToEntity(input, entity);

                // `entity` has correct values before this line
                await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
                // `entity` is now soft deleted

                message = MapToEntityDto(entity);
            }

            if (input.GroupIds != null)
            {
                await _messageGroupAppService.UpdateMessageGroups(input.GroupIds, message.Id);
            }

            if (emailApprovers)
            {
                await EmailApprovers(message);
            }

            if (sendMessage)
            {
                await StartSendMessage((CreateUpdateMessageDto)message);
            }

            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Message class

```cs
[Table("BmMessages")]
public class Message : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    public const int MaxTitleLength = 50;
    public const int MaxBodyLength = 2000;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(MaxTitleLength)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(MaxBodyLength)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ApprovingUserId))]
    public User ApprovingUser { get; set; }
    public long? ApprovingUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(StateLookUpId))]
    public LookUp StateLookUp { get; set; }
    public int StateLookUpId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TypeLookUpId))]
    public LookUp TypeLookUp { get; set; }
    public int TypeLookUpId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyLookUpId))]
    public LookUp CompanyLookUp { get; set; }
    public int CompanyLookUpId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ScheduledTime { get; set; }

    public Message(string title, string body = null)
    {
        Title = title;
        Body = body;
    }

    public Message(int typeLookUpId, int stateLookUpId, int companyLookUpId, string title, string body = null)
    {
        TypeLookUpId = typeLookUpId;
        StateLookUpId = stateLookUpId;
        CompanyLookUpId = companyLookUpId;
        Title = title;
        Body = body;
    }
}
```

MessageDto class

```cs
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Message))]
public class MessageDto : FullAuditedEntityDto<int>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScheduledTime { get; set; }

    public User ApprovingUser { get; set; }
    public long? ApprovingUserId { get; set; }

    public int StateLookUpId { get; set; }
    public LookUp StateLookUp { get; set; }

    public int TypeLookUpId { get; set; }
    public LookUp TypeLookUp { get; set; }

    public int CompanyLookUpId { get; set; }
    public LookUp CompanyLookUp { get; set; }

    public int[] GroupIds { get; set; }

    public int RecipientCount { get; set; }
}
```

CreateUpdateMessageDto class

```cs
[AutoMapTo(typeof(Message))]
public class CreateUpdateMessageDto : FullAuditedEntityDto<int>
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(Message.MaxTitleLength)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(Message.MaxBodyLength)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScheduledTime { get; set; }

    public User ApprovingUser { get; set; }
    public long? ApprovingUserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StateLookUpId { get; set; }
    public LookUp StateLookUp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TypeLookUpId { get; set; }
    public LookUp TypeLookUp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompanyLookUpId { get; set; }
    public LookUp CompanyLookUp { get; set; }

    public int[] GroupIds { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator CreateUpdateMessageDto(MessageDto messageDto)
    {
        return new CreateUpdateMessageDto()
        {
            Id = messageDto.Id,
            Title = messageDto.Title,
            Body = messageDto.Body,
            ScheduledTime = messageDto.ScheduledTime,
            StateLookUpId = messageDto.StateLookUpId,
            StateLookUp = messageDto.StateLookUp,
            TypeLookUpId = messageDto.TypeLookUpId,
            TypeLookUp = messageDto.TypeLookUp,
            CompanyLookUpId = messageDto.CompanyLookUpId,
            CompanyLookUp = messageDto.CompanyLookUp,
            GroupIds = messageDto.GroupIds
        };
    }
}
```

Lookup class

```cs
[Table("BmLookUps")]
public class LookUp : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Group { get; set; }

    public LookUp(string title, string group)
    {
        Title = title;
        Group = group;
    }
}
```

Example input and result (some of these values are null in the input because they are populated server side)

```
Input
CreateUpdateMessageDto

ApprovingUser         = null,
ApprovingUserId       = null,
Body                  = "Lorem Ipsum",
CompanyLookUp         = null,
CompanyLookUpId       = 17,
CreationTime          = {12/20/2020 11:52:08 PM},
CreatorUserId         = null,
DeleterUserId         = null,
DeletionTime          = null,
GroupIds              = {int[0]},
Id                    = 73,
IsDeleted             = false,
LastModificationTime  = null,
LastModifierUserId    = null,
ScheduledTime         = {12/29/2020 11:08:00 PM},
StateLookUp           = null,
StateLookUpId         = 1,
Title                 = "Test",
TypeLookUp            = null,
TypeLookUpId          = 8

Output
MessageDto

ApprovingUser         = null,
ApprovingUserId       = null,
Body                  = "Lorem Ipsum",
CompanyLookUp         = null,
CompanyLookUpId       = 17,
CreationTime          = {12/20/2020 11:52:08 PM},
CreatorUserId         = null,
DeleterUserId         = 6,
DeletionTime          = {12/21/2020 1:33:52 AM},
GroupIds              = null,
Id                    = 73,
IsDeleted             = true, // THIS SHOULD BE FALSE
LastModificationTime  = {12/20/2020 11:52:13 PM},
LastModifierUserId    = 6,
RecipientCount        = 0,
ScheduledTime         = {12/29/2020 11:08:00 PM},
StateLookUp           = null,
StateLookUpId         = 1,
Title                 = "Test",
TypeLookUp            = null,
TypeLookUpId          = 8
```

Update:
As requested, here is the relevant code for the `GetLookup` method. It has 2 overloads.

```cs
public class LookUpAppService : ProjectAppServiceBase, ILookUpAppService
{
    private readonly IRepository<LookUp, int> _lookUpRepository;

    public LookUpAppService(IRepository<LookUp, int> lookUpRepository)
    {
        _lookUpRepository = lookUpRepository;
    }

    public async Task<LookUp> GetLookup(string Group, int Id)
    {
        return await _lookUpRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Group == Group && l.Id == Id);
    }
        
    public async Task<LookUp> GetLookup(string Group, string Title)
    {
        return await _lookUpRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Group == Group && l.Title == Title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to conflicting change tracking information in tracked entities.

Add `.GetAll().AsNoTracking()` as in:

```cs
public async Task<LookUp> GetLookup(string Group, int Id)
{
 // return await _lookUpRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Group == Group && l.Id == Id);
    return await _lookUpRepository.GetAll().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Group == Group && l.Id == Id);
}
    
public async Task<LookUp> GetLookup(string Group, string Title)
{
 // return await _lookUpRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Group == Group && l.Title == Title);
    return await _lookUpRepository.GetAll().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Group == Group && l.Title == Title);
}
```